# Beamer - Total frame number in roman

Tags: beamer, header-footer, page-numbering, roman

I am trying to get roman numbers for beamer footline. I tried the following code:

```
\documentclass[•]{beamer}
\renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{\roman{framenumber}}
\renewcommand{\inserttotalframenumber}{\roman{totalframenumber}}  
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
I need the frame number as "i/i"
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The code runs fine and the frame number is printed in roman, but the total frame number is still in the default format. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that there is no counter `totalframenumber`. Therefore `\roman{totalframenumber}` fails. Here is a possible solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{\roman{framenumber}}
\newcounter{numberoframes}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{numberoframes}{\inserttotalframenumber}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber/\roman{numberoframes}} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
I need the frame number as "i/i"  \dots 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test 3}
\dots finally I got it!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]